# Title displays oddly in side-by-side markdown view of review queue

Tags: bug, review, markdown

Was on the reopen review queue, and the title displays weird in side-by-side markdown

Inline
[image: Inline view of the title]

Side-by-side
[image: Side-by-side view of the title]

Side-by-side markdown
[image: Side-by-side w/ Markdown view of the title]

It looks more like the inline version than the side-by-side version.

This was on Code Review, [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/92395)